# encrypted request returns 415 status code in iOS

Tags: ios, encryption

I have used the Apple docs and the suggestions from this site to successfully encrypt a soap request.

I am getting back  **(0) <69e85088 38687d1a bd4e78a2 1d8c391c 0bcfb73f fa8a35d6 b25225c1 58ba14ac 92c47a5a 169da482 0f5af8b3 5522559c fda0e182 23634968 2d93eaba 13a24739 8860a0a7 8f827ef2 103a019f 7c8250fa c1f7333f cc40e6d9 03078308 e7c46281 f032680f bd6fbf8d 4077af79 9bb5c364 975a8414 1d56581a 3e3182d9 0fb31965 0fad495c b1773dfd 652e43d2 860d5c73 3a328253 12ec03e0 e75f1745 7ea6b254 6def8b2f 39d2533a dd97cd8a 23f55ed4 6a61986b 528436fc 45d283d2 486c0d6d 452284ab b47ce74e bab36833 03ea3453 afbb50b6 d13e1073 2673b10a 9f4b771e a3119f05 eee3508d 8cd7c803 898abada 3ef58e06 9f7dde79 98548f8d 71a87912>**

when i print out the status code from my encryptWithPublicKey method which suggests it has worked successfully.

When i make the requse

```
NSMutableURLRequest *faURLRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:svcURL]];
    [faURLRequest addValue:@"soapMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [faURLRequest addValue:@"application/soap; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSData *dta =[self encryptWithPublicKey:soapMessage];

    NSLog(@"%@",[dta description]);

    [faURLRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",dta.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [faURLRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

     [faURLRequest setHTTPBody:dta];
```

i get back a status code of 415.

Can anyone point me to what is wrong with my code?

The encryptWithPublicKey method is this:

```
- (NSData *)encryptWithPublicKey:(NSString *)requestString
{

OSStatus status = noErr;

size_t cipherBufferSize;
uint8_t *cipherBuffer;                     // 1

uint8_t *dataToEncrypt= (uint8_t *)[requestString UTF8String];



size_t dataLength = sizeof(dataToEncrypt)/sizeof(dataToEncrypt[0]);

SecKeyRef publicKey = NULL;                                 // 3

NSString *certPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"devservercertificate" ofType:@"pfx"];
NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:certPath];
CFDataRef certDataRef = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)certData;
//SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, certDataRef);

// Establish a chain of trust anchored on our bundled certificate.
SecIdentityRef myIdentity;
SecTrustRef myTrust;
extractIdentityAndTrust(certDataRef, &myIdentity, &myTrust);

SecCertificateRef myCertificate;
SecIdentityCopyCertificate(myIdentity, &myCertificate);
publicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(myTrust);

// NSLog(@"%@",publicKey);

//  Allocate a buffer

cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);

//  Error handling

if (cipherBufferSize < sizeof(dataToEncrypt)) {
    // Ordinarily, you would split the data up into blocks
    // equal to cipherBufferSize, with the last block being
    // shorter. For simplicity, this example assumes that
    // the data is short enough to fit.
    printf("Could not decrypt.  Packet too large.\n");
    return NULL;
}

// Encrypt using the public.
status = SecKeyEncrypt(    publicKey,
                       kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                       dataToEncrypt,
                       (size_t) dataLength,
                       cipherBuffer,
                       &cipherBufferSize
                       );                              // 8

//  Error handling
//  Store or transmit the encrypted text

if (publicKey) CFRelease(publicKey);

NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
free(cipherBuffer);
NSLog(@"(%d) %@", (int)status, encryptedData);
return encryptedData;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are casting the status to an `int` but it may not be an `int` on all platforms, `OSStatus` is a 32 bit signed integer.

Comment: Is your data size close to `cipherBufferSize` and if so have you accounted for the size of the padding?

Comment: the cipherGBufferSize is 173 bytes for the largest request and for most i have tried is 4-10 bytes

Comment: Zaph i used %ld as well and i got the same response.. Should i try something different?

Comment: You might examine it in the Xcode debugger LLDB. It is just that the published error codes are all negative yet you are logging a positive number.

Comment: what is the encoding of the encrypted data? maybe there is a 415 because the server is expecting utf-8 and the data have different encoding?

Comment: OSStatus = 0 means "no Error" if i am not mistaken. The rest of the status codes have negative values which is why i thought my code works as it is supposed to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question!

It appears that the header information was not correct for the SOAP service and also the request body had a mistype...

That will do in order to waste a few hours :D